# Windows 10 force 80% display scaling

Tags: windows-10, resolution, dpi, scaling

I would like to force 80% display scaling in Windows 10 Pro, so that it look more sharp and provide more workspace on my HD screen. The GPU is Intel, so upscaling resolution seems impossible.

Comment: Forcing 100 pixels into 80 pixels will make it **less sharp**